# mpi.gather not working for boost.mpi for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi, boost-mpi

I am trying to use mpi.gather in boost.mpi for python as shown below.

```
import mpi
print(mpi.rank)
mpi.gather(value=True, root=0)
```

When I run the program with the following command,

```
mpiexec -n 3 python mpi_test.py
```

the output is

```
2
1
0
```

(The order of the numbers might change.)

However, when I set `value` argument in mpi.gather to something other than boolean type, it gets stuck.
Do you have any idea of why this is happening?

I use mpich2(version 3.0.4), boost 1.61.0 and python 3.5.1.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:
The code which does not work is as shown below:

```
import mpi
print(mpi.rank)
mpi.gather(value='!', root=0)
```

I ran the above program with `mpirun -n 3 python mpi_test.py`, 
and got the following result (and again, the order of the numbers might be different),

```
2
1
```

The program should also output 0 but it got stuck. 
I tried several numbers of processes to use, but it
always gets stuck with the root rank remained unprinted.

It seems that the program ends only when `value` is set to `False` or `True`.

Comment: Could you post a sample code that did not work ? I tried `print mpi.gather(value='!', root=0)` and it worked fine.

Comment: @francis I updated the question. Interestingly `print mpi.gather(value='!', root=0)` does not work for me.